# Website deployment using SVN Tags

Tags: svn, deployment

I have looked around Stackoverflow and there has been a lot of really useful qustions and comments written about website deployment using SVN.  It seems to boil down to whether you use 'export and rsync' or 'checkout and update'.

For a number of reasons, and after quite a bit of research, I have decided to use the latter to deploy websites to a live server.  As you would expect, I want to deploy tags, and therefore have the following question.

Is there anything obviously problematic with using the SVN switch command to switch the live server's repository to the new tag, each time an new tag is created?

There doesn't seem to be much written about this when I google it, so was wondering if I am missing something quite obvious.

Thank

Comment: One thing I can think of is that in the event something goes wrong you can't simply switch a symlink to revert to the previous version.

Comment: Good point, you would need to switch the repo back to a previous stable tag.

Comment: just curious what are your reasons for doing a checkout which will then include all of the .svn files and meta data?

Comment: Mainly due to uploaded CMS files on the live server.  A checkout rather than export would mean the same files and structure remains consistent.  I understand there are ways around this, but at the moment, I don't really have the time to setup a full deployment system.